# Unable to attach additional serial ports to a RHEL6 server with 8 serial ports

Tags: centos, redhat, serial

I have a RHEL6.9 server with 8 serial ports attached.
RHEL has configured 4 of them /dev/ttyS0-3, they have addresses and IRQ's.

I've been using the mknod command to create the devices /dev/ttyS[0-3]. I know IRQ 5 and 7 are free (I'm not using any parallel ports)

I've been using something like

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS4 c 4 64
```

However, it seems to just duplicate /dev/ttyS0 with the same address and IRQ, however, when I change this 2 5 I just get "No such device or address" from

```
 setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0-9]
```

The man page suggests the last 2 parameters (4 64) are versions. I naively assumed the 4 mapped to the IRQ.

Am I approaching this the right way, assuming I can just create new serial devices and assign an address and IRQ ?

If so (warning follow up question), can I get the addresses from somewhere on the running Linux system ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked kernel boot logs which addresses and IRQs are allocated to the serial ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment the second number in the `mknod` command but leave the first one alone. For example ...

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS4 c 4 68
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS5 c 4 69
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS6 c 4 70
mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS7 c 4 71
```

The two numbers are the major and minor device numbers. Major device number will stay the same for devices of the same type. Minor device number will change for each instance.

As you're using RHEL 6.x you could equivalently use the `MAKEDEV` command which calculates the number for you ...

```
$ cd /dev
$ sudo MAKEDEV -vx ttyS4
create ttyS4                          c   4  68 root:uucp 660 system_u:object_r:tty_device_t:s0
$ ls -l ttyS4
crw-rw----. 1 root uucp 4, 68 Apr 26 12:02 ttyS4
```

NB you don't need the `-v` flag, that just makes things verbose but you **do** want the `-x` flag (for exact) otherwise `MAKEDEV` will create any devices matching the given string (so ttyS40, ttyS41 etc)

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation makes perfect sense.